# Bash pipeline signal propagation - how does it work?

Tags: bash

While answering [this](https://superuser.com/q/1260900/707676) question, I was unable to fully explain how signals propagate through a pipeline.

Consider the following examples.

### Using `timeout` as the first element in the pipeline

This causes `gpg` to bail out having caught the `SIGTERM` that was delivered to `cat`, by `timeout`, leaving a broken file.

```
$ timeout 1 cat /dev/urandom | gpg -er attie@attie.co.uk > ./myfile.gpg

gpg: Terminated caught ... exiting
Terminated
$ gpg -d < ./myfile.gpg > /dev/null

You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
user: "Attie Grande <attie@attie.co.uk>"
4096-bit RSA key, ID C9AEA6AE, created 2016-12-13 (main key ID 7826F053)

gpg: encrypted with 4096-bit RSA key, ID C9AEA6AE, created 2016-12-13
      "Attie Grande <attie@attie.co.uk>"
gpg: block_filter 0x145e790: read error (size=14775,a->size=14775)
gpg: block_filter 0x145f110: read error (size=10710,a->size=10710)
gpg: WARNING: encrypted message has been manipulated!
gpg: block_filter: pending bytes!
gpg: block_filter: pending bytes!
```

### Using `timeout` in the middle of the pipeline

This works as expected - `gpg` exits cleanly.

```
$ cat /dev/urandom | timeout 1 cat | gpg -er attie@attie.co.uk > ./myfile.gpg
$ gpg -qd < ./myfile.gpg > /dev/null

You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
user: "Attie Grande <attie@attie.co.uk>"
4096-bit RSA key, ID C9AEA6AE, created 2016-12-13 (main key ID 7826F053)
```

### Using `SIGUSR1` instead of `SIGTERM`

Again, this works as expected - `gpg` exits cleanly. I expect because `cat` quits on `SIGUSR1`, while `gpg` ignores it.

```
$ timeout -sUSR1 1 cat /dev/urandom | gpg -er attie@attie.co.uk > ./myfile.gpg
$ gpg -qd < ./myfile.gpg > /dev/null

You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
user: "Attie Grande <attie@attie.co.uk>"
4096-bit RSA key, ID C9AEA6AE, created 2016-12-13 (main key ID 7826F053)
```

### Using process substitution

Again, this works - though I hadn't expected it to.

```
$ gpg -er attie@attie.co.uk > ./myfile.gpg < <( timeout 1 cat /dev/urandom )
$ gpg -qd < ./myfile.gpg > /dev/null

You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
user: "Attie Grande <attie@attie.co.uk>"
4096-bit RSA key, ID C9AEA6AE, created 2016-12-13 (main key ID 7826F053)
```

---

I can only presume that the signal of the first element in the pipeline is propagated through to the rest of the elements in the pipeline (even separating them with `timeout cat | cat | gpg` fails).

I've had a look for documentation, and had a play with `set -e`, `set -o pipefail` but they didn't act as I was expecting.

- What is actually going on?
- What are the semantics?
- Do we have any control over this?
- Is there a better way than moving the signal-generating-process form the front of the pipeline?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I can only presume that the signal of the first element in the pipeline is propagated through to the rest of the elements in the pipeline.

As far as I know there's no such propagation. I'm going to answer mainly your first question:

> What is actually going on?

### Short answer

(This may be somewhat simplified.)

1. When running a pipe, interactive `bash` starts every process in a process group with `PGID` (process group ID) equal to the `PID` (process ID) of the first part of the pipe.
2. `timeout` changes its own `PGID` to its own `PID`. This changes nothing if `timeout` is the first command in the pipe.
3. `timeout` sends the signal not only to the underlying command but to its entire process group as well. If `timeout` is the first command in the pipeline then its process group will still include `gpg`, therefore `gpg` will get the signal.

The phenomenon is researched and elaborated below.

---

### Elaboration

#### 1. `bash` behavior

When running a pipe, interactive `bash` starts every process in a process group with `PGID` (process group ID) equal to the `PID` (process ID) of the first part of the pipe. It's not really about interactive or not; it's about job control being enabled or not. Job control is enabled by default in interactive Bash, disabled in non-interactive. You can make your own tests (see [*Is it possible to get process group ID from `/proc?`*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/132224/108618)). I haven't researched more complex possibilities (e.g. what if the first "command" is a subshell?), in your case they don't matter. What matters is that `gpg` in these commands

```
timeout 1 cat /dev/urandom | gpg -er attie@attie.co.uk > ./myfile.gpg
cat /dev/urandom | timeout 1 cat | gpg -er attie@attie.co.uk > ./myfile.gpg
timeout -sUSR1 1 cat /dev/urandom | gpg -er attie@attie.co.uk > ./myfile.gpg
gpg -er attie@attie.co.uk > ./myfile.gpg < <( timeout 1 cat /dev/urandom )
```

gets `PGID` equal to the `PID` of

- `timeout`
- (the first) `cat`
- `timeout`
- `gpg` (i.e. itself)

respectively.

#### 2. `timeout` changes its own `PGID` (or not)

Run `strace timeout 1 cat` and you will see among other things:

```
setpgid(0, 0)
```

An excerpt from `man 2 setpgid`:

> ```
> int setpgid(pid_t pid, pid_t pgid);
> ```
>
> `setpgid()` sets the `PGID` of the process specified by `pid` to `pgid`. If `pid` is zero, then the process ID of the calling process is used. If `pgid` is zero, then the `PGID` of the process specified  by  `pid`  is  made  the  same as its process ID.

This means `timeout` sets its `PGID` equal to its `PID`. There are two possibilities:

- if `timeout` is the first command, its `PGID` is the same before and after `setpgid`, so `gpg` still has the same `PGID` as `timeout`;
- if `timeout` is not the first command, its `PGID` is changed and even if `gpg` had initially the same `PGID` as `timeout` the two `PGID`s are different now.

#### 3. `timeout` sends more signals than you expected

The same `strace timeout 1 cat` reveals lines like:

```
kill(19401, SIGTERM)
…
kill(0, SIGTERM)
```

In this example `19401` is the `PID` of `cat`. If you used `-s USR1` then there will be `SIGUSR1` instead of `SIGTERM` etc. This second `kill` is responsible for what you thought was a signal propagation through the pipeline. See `man 2 kill` (excerpt):

> ```
> int kill(pid_t pid, int sig);
> ```
>
> If `pid` equals `0`, then `sig` is sent to every process in the process group of the calling process.

The calling process is `timeout`. It sends the signal to its entire process group. I admit I don't know for sure what the purpose of this behavior is. I guess `timeout` is deliberately designed to signal its child *and* descendants of its child. Unless some descendant leaves the process group, all descendants will get the signal.

So if `timeout` is the first command in the pipeline then the chosen signal will be sent to every part of it (well, almost; consider another `timeout` in the same pipeline). This includes `gpg`. Then it's up to `gpg` how it reacts to the signal.

---

### Other questions

> Do we have any control over this? Is there a better way than moving the signal-generating-process from the front of the pipeline?

My quick search yielded no common tool to set/change `PGID`. I think you can write your own program that will call `setpgid(2)` or so. But now, when we know what is going on, moving `timeout` from the front of the pipeline seems to be a quite sane approach. There is another way: you can (temporarily) disable job control in your interactive Bash. Doing this in a subshell looks like a good idea:

```
(set +m; timeout … | gpg …)
```

Also note this is because of how `timeout` behaves. Other signal-generating-processes may not need such workaround.