# Kde, opening a new terminal window to ssh from bash script

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, terminal, kde

I have a bash scrip that does some environment setup, one of the steps require me to use SSH tunneling for licensing. The script I have works fine on a gnome environment, but I'm having trouble getting it to work on kde.

```
gnome-terminal -- ssh -L <>
```

What's the equivalent of that for kde? I've tried `konsole --new-tab`, this opens a new tab but doesn't execute anything and I can't go back to my previous terminal unless I close this new window.

I've also tried using `xterm` with `xterm -e ssh -L` but same issue, I can't use my previous terminal without closing this session and doing so would result in the license check failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Analysis

Your command:

> ```
> gnome-terminal -- ssh -L …
> ```

when run from a shell or from a shell script runs synchronously. The shell waits for it to exit before accepting the next command. The important thing is `gnome-terminal` does few things to exit early.

If `gnome-terminal` runs from within `gnome-terminal` (so the environment contains `GNOME_TERMINAL_*` variables) then the new `gnome-terminal` process will delegate the task to the already running `gnome-terminal` and exit.

If not from within `gnome-terminal` then yet another new `gnome-terminal` will be created to handle the task with no connection to the original terminal and your script. The `gnome-terminal` process your script spawned will exit after delegating the task.

So in any case `ssh` will run under `gnome-terminal` that is not a child of your script. The child of your script will exit early and allow the script to continue.

With `konsole` or `xterm` it's different. The very process your script spawns handles the task of being the terminal emulator for `ssh`, so your script doesn't continue until you close the new window.

---

#### Solutions

There are few solutions:

- Use `gnome-terminal`. You don't need full Gnome desktop to use this program. I use KDE Plasma and I have installed `gnome-terminal` for testing, to be able to answer questions like this.

  Your script will (still) depend on `gnome-terminal`.
- Spawn `xterm` (or `konsole` or whatever) *asynchronously*: **`xterm -e ssh -L … &`. I think this may be the simplest solution.** The `xterm` process will be a child of your script but the script won't wait for it. Note the script cannot easily tell if `ssh` authenticated yet and if port forwarding works; but I guess the same problem occurs with `gnome-terminal`, so probably your script takes this into consideration.

  Your script will depend on `xterm` (or `konsole` or whatever).
- Use a terminal multiplexer: `screen` or `tmux`.

  Your script will depend on `screen` or `tmux`. This seems no better than the above alternatives, but these terminal multiplexers are not associated to any desktop environment and they work even without any desktop. I'm mentioning them to make the answer more complete.
- Run `ssh` without creating any additional terminal. See below.

  Your script will get rid of one dependency.

---

#### Running `ssh` without creating additional terminal

In many cases this solution is the most elegant. It may or may not be good for you. You haven't revealed what your `ssh` does on the remote side. If it's only about forwarding ports (so you can use `ssh -N`) or if the command to run on the remote side is non-interactive then you should use `ssh -f`:

> `-f`
> Requests `ssh` to go to background just before command execution. This is useful if `ssh` is going to ask for passwords or passphrases, but the user wants it in the background. […]

Even if your `ssh` is not going to ask for passwords/passphrases, `-f` is better than `ssh … &` because you can use it with `-o ExitOnForwardFailure` and check its exit status before you assume the tunnel works.

Additionally use `-o ControlMaster=yes -o ControlPath=…` (in short `-MS …`) so you can easily terminate the master `ssh` later with `-O exit`. In [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1366032/432690) you will find a script that does this. A perfect script would terminate the master connection and clean up before exiting, even if terminated with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (use `trap`).

OTOH if you can set things up so `ssh` does not ask for anything then consider `autossh` in the background (`autossh … &`) to create a tunnel *and keep trying to renew it* in case the connection breaks. See the last part of [this other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1459025/432690).

Comment: Thank you, the xterm command with the `&` did the job for me.